# Game Center in Swift Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, game-center-leaderboard

I am trying to add Game Center Leaderboards and achievements into my game but I can not find any tutorials for SpriteKit in Swift. All of the tutorials have

```
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but in Sprite Kit that doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just call it like that, if you are in a `UIViewController` already. But if you want to show an `UIViewController` from your `SKScene` you should access the `rootViewController` and present the controller from there:

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```